# What is this meaning?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> "gorra light 'ave yer"

I found this in OED, but what is this?
What are the correct spellings?

Comment: Could you give us a link to where you found it? It's a spoken version of "Got a light, have you?" where the speaker is asking for a cigarette lighter.

Answer (score 5):

> Got a light, have you?

Or in a more basic order:

> Have you got a light?

The speaker wants to smoke a cigarette and needs something to light it with.

Answer (score 4):

This is thick [eye-dialect spelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_dialect) of some British English accent (possibly [Cockney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockney#Speech) or [Estuary English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estuary_English), but I'm not an expert on British accents). The words meant here are:

> Got a light, have you?

which is a way of asking the question, "*Have you got a light?*" (or more simply "*Do you have a light?*").